# Is there macros for rewrite CPS?

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, continuations, callcc, continuation-passing

For example I have two async methods

```
(get-a 10 (lambda (a) (get-b a (lambda (b) (display b)))
```

but I want to write something similar to

```
(define (a (get-a 10)))
(define (b (get-b a)))
(display b)
```

Answer (score 6):

No.  CPS is a global transformation, and macros local transformers.  See also "On the Expressive Power of Programming Languages".